# To find my guest user account again

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, login, merge-accounts

I am hesitating too much in asking this question as a new user.I participate in Math stack exchange question answer site almost 10 days ago as a guest & I earned 45 reputations.But 3 days ago my system attacked by a virus & Mozilla firefox which I used to surf internet is infected. i can't format my system because there is very useful data stored in it & my antivirus was also expired. Ultimately I have last option what I know to uninstall that & I did that & now I use Google chrome instead of Mozilla firefox but now I can't find my account & site shows the process to make a new account. If I can again access that account please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access your old account and/or merge it with your current (registered) one, you will have to contact the SE developers, since it will involve modifications to and searches in the database that is outside the powers of the community moderators.

Please navigate to the bottom of this page and click on the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link, and:

1. Explain that you would like to re-gain access to your previous guest account.
2. Give information that may be useful for searching for your previous guest account. If you know your user ID for the guest account it will be helpful. If you know the e-mail address you used for that account it will also.
3. Follow the instructions sent to you by the SE team (they may ask for further information to help find the account or to prove that you are the same user).